# Why can't I restart/stop PyCharms Console after using parallel-processing (njobs=-1) in sklearn?

Tags: parallel-processing, scikit-learn, pycharm

Im working with sklearn in Pycharm. When I use an estimator that is capable of parallel processing (e.g. RandomForestClassifier) and set `n_jobs` to `-1` I can not restart the console after running my module.
In debugging mode however, it is possible to restart the debugger.

[image]

This behaviour is reproducible. Although it is not occurent in all kind of pipelines, but seems to occur especially in ones with high computational costs.

Does anybody has an idea, how to fix this problem?